# How to control order that user enters inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this form with several inputs. I want to make it so that input 1 has to be set before input 2. Id like to make input two readonly until input one has been entered.

```html
<form>
  Input-1:<br>
  <input type="text" name="first" id="one"><br>
  Input-2:<br>
  <input type="text" name="second" id="two" readonly>
</form>
```

Im not sure how I can accomplish this. Jquery?

Comment: On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, ad Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for this. One way to achieve it in vanilla JS would be like this: *(Red means `readonly`, green mean OK)*

```js
document.querySelector('#one').onchange = (ev) => {
  if(ev.target.value !== '') {
    document.querySelector('#two').readOnly = false;
  } else {
    document.querySelector('#two').readOnly = true;
  }
};
```

```css
#two[readonly] {
  background-color: rgba(255, 69, 0, 0.5);
}
#two {
  background-color: rgba(76, 187, 23, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="one"><br>  
<input type="text" id="two" readonly>
```